# Python Namespaces and Modules

Tags: python, module, namespaces

If I import a python module using a syntax like this:

```
import my_module
```

I can later use a number of simplest command to get an idea of what the module is, where it is located and etc. For example:

```
print(my_module)
```

outputs: module 'my_module' from 'my_module.py'

```
dir(my_module)
```

outputs: ['MyClass', '**builtins**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**', 'math', 'os', 'sys']

I even can find out an absolute path of the module by using:

```
print os.path.abspath( my_module.__file__  )
```

outputs: /Users/julia/Documents/classes/my_module.py

But if instead of import 'my_module' I would be using:

```
from my_module import MyClass
```

all I can is to:

```
print MyClass
```

which outputs: my_module.MyClass

I do see MyClass came from my_module file. But unfortunately that is all I can get since none of the commands I used to use to get the info on module doesn't work. Here is use and their output:

```
print dir(my_module.MyClass)  NameError: name 'my_module' is not defined

print dir(my_module)  NameError: name 'my_module' is not defined

print my_module  name 'my_module' is not defined
```

What command(-s) should I be using while tracking down the imported modules brought with

```
from my_module import MyClass
```

syntax?

Comment: huh? whats the question? if you just import MyClass ... you have only imported that class...

Comment: this worked for me. perhaps you don't import that module at all, and want to print its detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that

```
from my_module import MyClass
```

only imports MyClass but not the whole Module.

If you want to know the name of the Module MyClass was imported from, you can use:

```
print MyClass.__module__
```

If you want to use other Stuff from the same Module you could use:

```
my_module = __import__(MyClass.__module__)
print dir(my_module)
```

But it would be far more easy to just write:

```
import my_module
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr.Crash!
Here is the summary:

If the module was imported with:

```
from my_module import MyClass
```

don't call the module by using its name directly.
Instead get to it via class imported from this module (using class's **module** attr) such as:

```
print dir(MyClass.__module__)
print os.path.abspath( MyClass.__module__ )
```